# Interjections quand on place un objet physique quelque part

Tags: interjections

Y a-t-il un nom ou une catégorie spéciale pour les interjections que certains francophones utilisent pour "accompagner" le déplacement (par eux-mêmes) d'un objet physique ?

Exemples:

- Lorsque A pose la salière sur la table, elle dit "Hop !"
- Lorsque B replace la salière dans son rangement, il dit "Toc !"

Des allemands m'ont demandé pourquoi les francophones emploient ces interjections, je ne m'en étais jamais rendu compte donc j'ai observé attentivement les gens, et effectivement beaucoup de francophones utilisent ces interjections quand ils déplacent des objets. Y a-t-il un nom pour cela ? [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection#Les_divers_types_d.27interjections) n'en parle pas. Bonus pour d'autres exemples similaires.

Comment: Personnellement, je n'ai jamais entendu "Toc !" dans ce contexte...

Comment: @Random: J'avais la même impression, avant d'observer les gens attentivement :-)

Comment: Il y a aussi _Ho hisse_ pour se donner du courage lorsque la salière est trop grosse pour être déplacée par une seule personne.

Answer (score 3):

Dans la [liste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection#Les_divers_types_d.27interjections) dont tu parles :

> #### Les divers types d'interjections
>
> Les onomatopées, [...]
>
> - soit naturelle tels : [...] Hop ! [...]
> - soit liées aux objets humains [...] Toc-toc !

Il s'agit d'onomatopées utilisées comme **[Voilà](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voil%C3%A0)** :

> 1. Introduit une personne, une chose ou son action que l’interlocuteur peut sentir, très souvent visuellement. [...]

Comment: Donc ce sont des "onomatopées naturelles", c'est ça ? Je pense que "Toc-toc !" appartient à une catégorie différente, celle qui simplement imite les sons existants.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul J'imagine que tu n'as pas été voir sur la liste. J'ai remis en forme comme sur la page d'origine pour faire ressortir les différents types d'onomatopées.

Comment: J'ai lu l'article en détail, mais je voulais simplement dire que "Toc-toc !" n'appartient pas à la catégorie d'onomatopées décrite par ma question, c'est très différent de "Toc !" :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Non. "Toc" vient de l'utilisation de plus en plus courante de "Toc-toc" qu'on a voulu singulariser.

Answer (score 0):

Il s'agit tout bonnement des [onomatopées](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/onomatop%C3%A9e), avec un son qui approche le son de l'action:

- plouf (un objet qui tombe dans l'eau)
- glou-glou (gargarismes)
- bam (objet violemment posé)
- paf (similaire mais moins fort)
- toc (petit bruit frappé sur du bois)
- ding (cloche)
- crrrr (bruit de crissement ...)
- divers chuintements, etc.